# Can someone explain me the parameter RETURN_VALUE?

Tags: sql-server, asp-classic, sql-server-2000, ado

I want to know what does RETURN_VALUE mean! I'm stuck at this thing. How to use RETURN_VALUE in a SQL Server stored procedure? thanks..

ASP:

```
Set cmdDB = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
With cmdDB
   .ActiveConnection = ADOConM
   .CommandText = "usp_jaljava_member_select"
   .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
   .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("RETURN_VALUE", adInteger, adParamReturnValue, 0)
   .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@TLoginName", adVarChar, adParamInput, 15, lcase(TLoginName))
   .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@TPassword", adVarChar, adParamInput, 20, TPassword)
   .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@retval", adVarChar, adParamOutput, 50)
```

'   .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@TPinCode", adVarChar, adParamInput, 15,TPinCode)
       .Execute,,adExecuteNoRecords

```
   RetVal = .Parameters("@retval")
   Ret = Trim(.Parameters("RETURN_VALUE"))

   'Set .ActiveConnection = Nothing
End With
Set cmdDB = Nothing

UTid = RetVal
```

SQL Server stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_jaljava_member_select 
   @TLoginName varchar(15),
   @TPassword varchar(20),
   @retval varchar(50) OUTPUT
   --@TPinCode varchar(15)
AS
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A MS SQL stored procedure can return a `return value` - this is apart from output parameters.

The code above gives you access to this return value.

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174998.aspx) for more information (RETURN (Transact-SQL)).

So, for the following stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE checkstate @param varchar(11)
AS
   IF (SELECT StateProvince FROM Person.vAdditionalContactInfo WHERE ContactID = @param) = 'WA'
   RETURN 1
ELSE
   RETURN 2;
GO
```

The following code would set `Ret` to 1 or 2, depending on the passed in parameter and data:

```
Set cmdDB = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
With cmdDB
    .ActiveConnection = ADOConM
    .CommandText = "checkstate"
    .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
    .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("RETURN_VALUE", adInteger, adParamReturnValue, 0)
    .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@param", adVarChar, adParamInput, 11, "Contact")

    .Execute,,adExecuteNoRecords

    Ret = Trim(.Parameters("RETURN_VALUE"))

End With
Set cmdDB = Nothing
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the value that would be returned from the Stored procedure.

From [Using a Stored Procedure with Output Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378108(SQL.90).aspx)

> A SQL Server stored procedure that you
>   can call is one that returns one or
>   more OUT parameters, which are
>   parameters that the stored procedure
>   uses to return data back to the
>   calling application.

From the link

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetImmediateManager
   @employeeID INT,
   @managerID INT OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
   SELECT @managerID = ManagerID 
   FROM HumanResources.Employee 
   WHERE EmployeeID = @employeeID
END

public static void executeStoredProcedure(Connection con) {
   try {
      CallableStatement cstmt = con.prepareCall("{call dbo.GetImmediateManager(?, ?)}");
      cstmt.setInt(1, 5);
      cstmt.registerOutParameter(2, java.sql.Types.INTEGER);
      cstmt.execute();
      System.out.println("MANAGER ID: " + cstmt.getInt(2));
   }
   catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, the parameter name for return value could be anything.
If your stored procedure returns a value, it could be written as

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_jaljava_member_select 
@TLoginName varchar(15),
@TPassword varchar(20),
@retval varchar(50) OUTPUT
--@TPinCode varchar(15)
AS

BEGIN
declare @errorCodeInCaseOfAnError int

Return @errorCodeInCaseOfAnError
END
```